# Connect a microcontroller to a gadget

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, voltage, parallel, opto-isolator

Although I have average programming skills, I'm not far from being an noob concerning electronics!

I therefore want to kindly ask you to help me connect my (already programmed) Arduino Uno to the gadget where it should fulfill it's duties.

[image]

As you can see I want the mc to "know" every time the circuit at the bottom closes.

I also want the mc to be able to bypass the switch on the top.

I wanted to use opto-isolators for this purpose, as an opto-isolator would guarantee that my project never could damage the original gadget.

As you can see the main problem is the different voltages.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the voltage across the switch?

Comment: Also, what is the component in the bottom circuit?

Comment: Hi Majenko! The component in the bottom circuit is a bell (or to be precise an electronic bell). I don't know the voltage across the switch. I could check it out, but as I just wanted to bypass the switch I thought that would not matter!? Voltage shouldn't be too high.

Comment: @Marcel You'll have to bypass the existing switch with basically another switch. The main difference is that instead of using a mechanical switch, you'll be using one that is electronically controller. That can be a simple transistor or a some sort of relay. In any case, the "switch" you'll put in parallel with the existing switch must be able to at least sustain the voltage and the current that are in the circuit. Also can you connect the device's and Arduino's grounds? That would make things much simpler.

Comment: Thank you AndrejaKo! I would like to use an opto-isolator instead of a transistor. I think with opto-isolators also it is not necessary to connect the device's ground with the Arduino's ground. I just tried to measure the switche's voltage. Maybe I did it wrong but I think it's 0.05 V.

Answer (score 2):

For the switch at the top you can use a relay, or something like an [OptoMOS](http://uk.farnell.com/nec/ps7141e-1a-a/optocoupler-ssr-mosfet-dip-6/dp/1682877).

For the buzzer detection an [optoisolator](http://uk.farnell.com/vishay/vo2601/optocoupler-10mbd-5kv-us-8pin/dp/1779721) with gate output with anode to buzzer +V and cathode to ground via whatever resistor is necessary to set the current specified in the datasheet - 15mA in the one linked to with a Vf of 1.4V. so if your high voltage is ~2V then 2 - 1.6 / 0.015 = 40 ohms needed. I'm assuming the low voltage is ~0V here.

As it's an open collector output, You can wire the output straight to your Arduino pin and set a weak pullup (or just use the pin normally and use a 10k pullup to +V.

Answer (score 1):

You can go old school and use 2 relays.

You mcu can control a 5V relay that will open/close that gap up there.

Then you must find out what voltage you have on the output from the gadget and you can put a relay in parallel with that lamp/bell or whatever that is.

The nice thing with relays is that they are also isolated from the target, and you will get a lot of nice "clicks" from the system when it is in action.

Comment: Yes, there's a simplicity in using relays.  However we don't know that the gadget's existing output is up to driving a relay.  If that's a mechanical buzzer it probably is up to driving a small relay with a low current coil, but we don't really know.